# Using multiple angular filters within an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a standard JSON that I am outputting on a div using ng-repeat.

```
[
 {
   "info": "CA",
   "label": "STATE",
   "displayLabel": "['pInformation']['State__c']",
   "type": "string",
   "group": "Custom Properties",
   "collapse": true,
   "editing": false
 },
 {
    "info": "2017-04-17T23:29:37.000Z",
    "label": "Date Time",
    "displayLabel": "['pInformation']['DateTime__c']",
    "type": "string",
    "group": "Custom Properties",
    "collapse": true,
    "editing": false
  },
 {
    "info": "2017-23-17T23:32:37.000Z",
    "label": "Date",
    "displayLabel": "['pInformation']['Date__c']",
    "type": "string",
    "group": "Custom Properties",
    "collapse": true,
    "editing": false
  }
]

<dl ng-repeat="fields in data.fields">
   <dd>{{fields.label}}</dd>
   <dd>{{fields.info}}</dd>
</dl>
```

If I wanted to add an angular date filter for the 2nd and 3rd node:

- 2nd: date: 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'
- 3rd: date: 'MM-dd-yyyy'

Answer (score 0):

Use $index:

```
<dl ng-repeat="fields in data.fields">
<div ng-show="$index != 1 || $index != 2">
   <dd>{{fields.label}}</dd>
   <dd>{{fields.info}}</dd>
 </div>   
<div ng-show="$index == 1 || $index== 2">
   <dd>{{fields.label}}</dd>
   <dd>{{fields.info || someDateFilter}}</dd>
 </div>  
</dl>
```